# How to automatically set Google Maps Viewport contain a list of Markers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geometry

I want to automatically center the Google Map of the plugin `google_maps_flutter` in Flutter with a list of markers. The markers are returned from an API and I would like to open the Google Map with a `CameraPosition` containing all markers with some padding. How would I do that?

I've used [that](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter) example to integrate the map.

Comment: most likely you need [CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/CameraUpdate/newLatLngBounds.html) - the docs say: *"Returns a camera update that transforms the camera so that the specified geographical bounding box is centered in the map view at the greatest possible zoom level. A non-zero padding insets the bounding box from the map view's edges. The camera's new tilt and bearing will both be 0.0."*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample to show 2 markers. You can get the south west and north east locations from markers list.

```
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: _initPosition,
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {  
    //Camera Update to include 2 marker location
    LatLngBounds bound;
    if (loc1.lat > loc2.lat &&
        loc1.lng > loc2.lng) {
      bound = LatLngBounds(
        southwest: LatLng(loc2.lat, loc2.lng),
        northeast: LatLng(loc1.lat, loc1.lng),
      );
    } else if (loc1.lng > loc2.lng) {
      bound = LatLngBounds(
          southwest: LatLng(loc1.lat, loc2.lng),
          northeast: LatLng(loc2.lat, loc1.lng));
    } else if (loc1.lat > loc2.lat) {
      bound = LatLngBounds(
          southwest: LatLng(loc2.lat, loc1.lng),
          northeast: LatLng(loc1.lat, loc2.lng));
    } else {
      bound = LatLngBounds(
        southwest: LatLng(loc1.lat, loc1.lng),
        northeast: LatLng(loc2.lat, loc2.lng),
      );
    }

    CameraUpdate u2 =
        CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bound, 50);
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500))
        .then((value) => controller.animateCamera(u2));
  },  
)
```